# Fetch React search data

Tags: reactjs, firebase, search, fetch-api

I have a problem that when I search a Data in my firebase database with react dom js , i cann't get my expected data. Basically, I dont get any data at this time.

```
export default function SearchBar(){
    const [data, setData] = useState([]);
    const [search, setSearch] = useState("");

    useEffect(() => {
        fetch('<URL ...>')
        .then(response => response.json())
        .then(data => {
            // console.log(data);
            if(data>0){
                setData(data)
            }
            // console.log(search);
            // console.log(data);
        })
        .catch(error => console.error(error));
    }, [search]);
    

    return <Form>
        <Input type="text" value={search} placeholder="Searching ..." onChange={event => setSearch(event.target.value)} />  
        <div className="" style={{height:"18px", color:'red'}}>
            {data.filter(item => item.toLowerCase().includes(search.toLowerCase())).map(item => (
                    <div key={item}>
                        {console.log(item)}
                    </div>
                ))
            }
        </div>
        
        <Button type="submit"><span class="material-symbols-outlined ">
            search
        </span>
        </Button>
    </Form>
}
```

I expect Get Data from my Firebase which i serach in my serachBox.

Comment: What is the returned data? An integer? If not, `data > 0` makes no sense.

Comment: Fatching Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'toLowerCase') when just set setData(data).

Comment: What is the returned data?

Comment: return Data is - [null, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…} ..... ... .  .  ..]. Here 0
: null
1: {noq: 4, title: 'PHP Programming Language Tutorial - Full Course', youtubeID: 'OK_JCtrrv-c'}

Comment: Update the question with the additional information.